# Convert dataset from wide to a longer format for two different set of columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is a bit too wide for the EDA plots I would like to make.

The data can be found here: [https://www.massey.ac.nz/~kgovinda/data/Bill_Colour.RData](https://www.massey.ac.nz/%7Ekgovinda/data/Bill_Colour.RData)

But looks something like this:

| CommonName | r_ChromaticityFemaleLowerMandible | r_ChromaticityFemaleUpperMandible | r_ChromaticityMaleLowerMandible | r_ChromaticityMaleUpperMandible | many more column ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| African_Broadbill | 0.3331 | 0.3109 | 0.3584 | 0.3573 | etc... |

I am pivoting it longer so that three columns are tacked on to the end while removing the four`r_*` Chromaticity columns

| LowerMandible | UpperMandible | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3331 | 0.3109 | Female |
| 0.3584 | 0.3573 | Male |
| 0.3473 | 0.340 | Male |

My current method of doing this requires two pivot_longer for upper and lower and then they are bonded together.

```
library(tidyverse)
load(url("https://www.massey.ac.nz/~kgovinda/data/Bill_Colour.RData"))

lowerMandible <- Bill_Colour %>%
  pivot_longer(c(r_ChromaticityFemaleLowerMandible, r_ChromaticityMaleLowerMandible),
               values_to = "LowerMandible") %>%
  select(-name)

upperMandible <- Bill_Colour %>%
  select(r_ChromaticityFemaleUpperMandible,
         r_ChromaticityMaleUpperMandible) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(r_ChromaticityFemaleUpperMandible, r_ChromaticityMaleUpperMandible),
               values_to = "UpperMandible") %>%
  mutate(Sex = as.factor(str_sub(name,15,-14))) %>%
  select(-name)


upperAndLowerBySex <- cbind.data.frame(lowerMandible, upperMandible) %>%
  select(-r_ChromaticityFemaleUpperMandible, -r_ChromaticityMaleUpperMandible)
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this with one set of `pivot_longer` rather than making multiple datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by renaming the columns to appropriate strings which can be processed by `pivot_longer` and its `names_sep` argument.

We need to rename the desired columns; e.g. from `r_ChromaticityMaleLowerMandible` to `LowerMandible_Male`. See this https://regex101.com/r/6QstQq/1 to better understand the regex pattern.

Then we can simply use `pivot_longer` and apply it on the columns that contain `Mandible` in their names. By providing multiple values to `names_to` and a parser to `names_sep` we can break the pivoted columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
load(url("https://www.massey.ac.nz/~kgovinda/data/Bill_Colour.RData"))
```

```
Bill_Colour %>% 
  select(contains("r_Chromaticity")) %>% ## you can select other columns as needed
  rename_with(~str_replace(.x, "(r_Chromaticity)(.*ale)(.*)", "\\3_\\2"), 
              contains("r_Chromaticity")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(., 
               cols = contains("Mandible"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "sex"),
               names_sep = "_")
```

```
#> # A tibble: 3,210 x 3
#>    sex    LowerMandible UpperMandible
#>    <chr>          <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 Female         0.333         0.311
#>  2 Male           0.358         0.357
#>  3 Female         0.347         0.341
#>  4 Male           0.359         0.394
#>  5 Female         0.352         0.430
#>  6 Male           0.370         0.443
#>  7 Female         0.370         0.375
#>  8 Male           0.378         0.351
#>  9 Female         0.336         0.329
#> 10 Male           0.343         0.335
#> # ... with 3,200 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The trick to doing this in a single `pivot_longer` call is to get your column names into a desirable form, where you have some separator between the new column name (`LowerMandible` or `UpperMandible`) and the value you're using to expand the rows (`Sex`). Then you can use the `names_sep` argument to indicate your separator and the `names_to` argument to describe where they're being mapped:

```
upperAndLowerBySex <- Bill_Colour %>%
  rename("LowerMandible_Female" = "r_ChromaticityFemaleLowerMandible",
         "LowerMandible_Male" = "r_ChromaticityMaleLowerMandible",
         "UpperMandible_Female" = "r_ChromaticityFemaleUpperMandible",
         "UpperMandible_Male" = "r_ChromaticityMaleUpperMandible") %>%
  pivot_longer(c(LowerMandible_Female, LowerMandible_Male,
                 UpperMandible_Female, UpperMandible_Male),
               names_to = c(".value", "Sex"),
               names_sep = "_")
head(upperAndLowerBySex[,c(1:2, 10:12)])
#     Row SpeciesName              Sex    LowerMandible UpperMandible
#   <dbl> <chr>                    <chr>          <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1     1 Smithornis_capensis      Female         0.333         0.311
# 2     1 Smithornis_capensis      Male           0.358         0.357
# 3     2 Smithornis_sharpei       Female         0.347         0.341
# 4     2 Smithornis_sharpei       Male           0.359         0.394
# 5     3 Smithornis_rufolateralis Female         0.352         0.430
# 6     3 Smithornis_rufolateralis Male           0.370         0.443
```

You can read more about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67995827/3093387).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The fundamental helpful bit of using the names_sep came from you. But have gone with the other for the check mark as that neat work with the regex is also helpful.